Brake pedal stiff to press and stays stuck down
Durango 2000 been just sitting for atleast a year. Brake pedal is stiff band stays down after pushing. You can pull it back up with foot. Brakes work but just hard to push but don’t return!

The obvious course is to get the brakes refurbished.

Sitting is not good because brake discs and rotors can wear.  Make sure fluid levels are up, but be prepared to swap master cylinder.
